# Create a loop in SAS which filters 2 variables simultaneously

Tags: sas

The question might be quite vague but I could not come up with a decent concise title.

I have data where there are `id` ,`date`, `amountA` and `AmtB` as my variables. The task is to pick the dates that are within 10 days of each other and then see if their `amountA` are within 20% and if they are then pick the one with highest `amountB`. I have used to this code to achieve this

```
id     date     amountA   amountB  
1    1/15/2014   1000     79  
1    1/16/2014   1100     81  
1    1/30/2014   700      50  
1    2/05/2014   710      80   
1    2/25/2014   720      50
```

This is what I need

```
id     date     amountA   amountB  
1    1/16/2014   1100     81  
1    1/30/2014   700      50    
1    2/25/2014   720      50
```

I wrote this code but the problem with this code is its not automatic and has to be done on a case to case basis.I need a way to loop it so that it automatically outputs the results.I am no pro at looping and hence am stuck.Any help is greatly appreciated

```
data test2;
set test1;
diff_days=abs(intck('days',first_dt,date));
if diff_days<=10 then flag=1;
else if diff_days>10 then flag=0;
run; 

data test3 rem_test3;
set test2;
if flag=1 then output test3;
else output rem_test3;
run;

proc sort data=test3;
by id amountA;
run;

data all_within;
set test3;
by id amountA;
amtA_lag=lag1(amountA);
if first.id then
  do;
      counter=1;
           flag1=1;
  end;
if first.id=0 then
 do;
counter+1;
      diff=abs(amountA-amtA_lag);
      if diff<(10/100*amountA) then flag1+1;
      else flag1=0;
 end;    
if last.stay and flag1=counter then output all_within;
run;
```

Comment: I was trying to understand the objective. As per requirement, second row In the output should be - (1    2/05/2014   710      80) than (1    1/30/2014   700      50) since AmountB is more for 02/05/2015 than on 01/30/2014. Is it right?

Comment: What behaviour do you expect when an observation can belong to two or more groups? For example `2015-01-01,1000,10`; `2015-01-09,1000,20`; `2015-01-18,1000,30`. With these observations how many outputs would you expect?

Comment: Harshad: I am extremely sorry.Yes you are right.

Comment: SRSwift: In the case you mentioned I would like it to retain 2015-01-09,1000,20 between  01-01,1000,10 and 2015-01-09,1000,20 since they are 10 days apart and since their amounts are also within 20 percent and then resolve between 2015-01-09,1000,20   and  2015-01-18,1000,30  and pick  2015-01-18,1000,30  since it has greater amount B.  So finally it should retain 2015-01-18,1000,30  .This is why I need the loop since it I have been doing this in multiple steps.Thank you .Please let me know if I wasn't clear

Comment: So your final output for the example would be one observation: `2015-01-18,1000,30`?

Comment: For your example, yes

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to group all records together that have (no skip of 10+ days) and (amt A w/in 20%)?

Looping isn't your problem - no explicitly coded loop is needed to do this (or at least, the way I think of it).  SAS does the data step loop for you.

What you want to do is:

- Identify groups.  A group is the consecutive records that you want to, among them, collapse to one row.  It's not perfectly clear to me how amountA has to behave here - does the whole group need to have less than a maximum difference of 10%, or a record to next record difference of < 10%, or a (current highest amtB of group) < 10% - but you can easily identify all of these rules.  Use a RETAINed variable to keep track of the previous amountA, previous date, highest amountB, date associated with the highest amountB, amountA associated with highest amountB.
- When you find a record that doesn't fit in the current group, output a record with the values of the previous group.

You shouldn't need two steps for this, although you can if you want to see it more easily - this may be helpful for debugging your rules.  Set it so that you have a GroupNum variable, which you RETAIN, and you increment that any time you see a record that causes a new group to start.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that I think should work. The basic approach is:

- Find all the pairs of sufficiently close observations
- Join the pairs with themselves to get all connected ids
- Reduce the groups
- Join to the original data and get the desired values

---

```
data have;
    input
        id
        date :mmddyy10.
        amountA
        amountB;
    format date mmddyy10.;
    datalines;
1 1/15/2014 1000 79
2 1/16/2014 1100 81
3 1/30/2014 700  50
4 2/05/2014 710  80
5 2/25/2014 720  50
;
run;

/* Count the observations */
%let dsid = %sysfunc(open(have));
%let nobs = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid., nobs));
%let rc = %sysfunc(close(&dsid.));

/* Output any connected pairs */
data map;
    array vals[3, &nobs.] _temporary_;
    set have;
    /* Put all the values in an array for comparison */
    vals[1, _N_] = id;
    vals[2, _N_] = date;
    vals[3, _N_] = amountA;
    /* Output all pairs of ids which form an acceptable pair */
    do i = 1 to _N_;
        if 
            abs(vals[2, i] - date) < 10 and
            abs((vals[3, i] - amountA) / amountA) < 0.2
        then do;
            id2 = vals[1, i];
            output;
        end;
    end;
    keep id id2;
run;
proc sql;
    /* Reduce the connections into groups */
    create table groups as
    select 
        a.id, 
        min(min(a.id, a.id2, b.id)) as group
    from map as a
    left join map as b
        on a.id = b.id2
    group by a.id;
    /* Get the final output */
    create table lookup (where = (amountB = maxB)) as
    select 
        have.*, 
        groups.group,
        max(have.amountB) as maxB
    from have 
    left join groups
        on have.id = groups.id
    group by groups.group;
quit;
```

The code works for the example data. However, the group reduction is insufficient for more complicated data. Fortunately, approaches for finding all the subgraphs given a set of edges can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525187/identifying-connected-graphs-given-edges), [here](https://communities.sas.com/docs/DOC-1268), [here](https://communities.sas.com/message/108509) or [here (using SAS/OR)](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ornoaug/67520/HTML/default/viewer.htm#ornoaug_optnet_details14.htm).

Comment: I think you'll find that your array isn't quite working as intended - I'll let you puzzle it out though.

Comment: Thanks. Two corrections made, shout if you spot any more errors.

Comment: You're populating the nth entry of the array on the nth iteration of the data step, rather than all entries on the 1st iteration and none on all the rest, which I suspect is what you're aiming for.

Comment: I see, but that was not my aim. My approach is to populate the array as each row is read in, then compare backwards against the populated values (hence `do i = 1 to _N_`). This way every pair is compared once and there is only one pass of the data (n reads, n writes, n * (n -1))/ 2 lookups). My corrections were aligning the first index and adding the macro variable creation.

Comment: Hi SRSwift, Sorry about the delayed response.I ran your code through the test data but I end up getting this WARNING: A GROUP BY clause has been transformed into an ORDER BY clause because neither the
         SELECT clause nor the optional HAVING clause of the associated table-expression
         referenced a summary function.

Comment: There was a comma missing from the final select. I've fixed it, and you should be able to run it now.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble figuring out the rules...but here is some code that checks each record against the previous for the criteria I think you want.

```
Data HAVE;
 input id     date :mmddyy10.    amountA   amountB  ;
 format date mmddyy10.;
 datalines;
1    1/15/2014   1000     79  
1    1/16/2014   1100     81  
1    1/30/2014   700      50  
1    2/05/2014   710      80   
1    2/25/2014   720      50   
;

Proc Sort data=HAVE;
 by id date;
Run;

Data WANT(drop=Prev_:);
 Set HAVE;

 Prev_Date=lag(date);
 Prev_amounta=lag(amounta);
 Prev_amountb=lag(amountb);

 If not missing(prev_date);

 If date-prev_date<=10 then do;
  If (amounta-prev_amounta)/amounta<=.1 then;
   If amountb<prev_amountb then do;
    Date=prev_date;
    AmountA=prev_amounta;
    AmountB=prev_amountb;
   end;
  end;
 Else delete;
Run;
```

Comment: Hi , Thank you Carolina.But my idea here is to condense and group everything untill I end up with all the observations that can no longer be grouped.As in this dataset. I want to end up with the following observations since  these observations are all more than ten days apart .I do not want to delete them if they do not meet the criteria .I just want to keep them the same instead of grouping them.                                                                                                      1    1/16/2014   1100     81  
1    2/05/2014   710      80   
1    2/25/2014   720      50