# SAS: recursively process dataset to get all connections between entities

Tags: recursion, sas, iteration, sas-macro

I have a bridging table `in01` that contains relations. E.g. Customer A is related to Customer B (which is then stored in a two duplicate records A/B and B/A).

```
/* 1. Testdata */
data in01(keep=primary: secondary:);
    infile datalines;
    length primary_party_no secondary_party_no $ 15;
    input primary_party_no secondary_party_no ;
    datalines;
A B
B A
A C
C A
B D
D B
W Z
Z W
Y Z
Z Y
X Y
Y X
;
run;
```

**Task:** My Task is group all customers with a connection and create an ID, regardless of the number of "links" required to connect the customers.

In the example above `Group 1` would consist of `A, B, C, D`, while `Group 2` would consist of `W, X, Y, Z`.

I reckon the the data has to be looped over recursively - I am, however, unable to figure out how to design a data step or macro that calls upon itself in each loop.

What would be a good starting point to tackle this problem?

Comment: Looks like you trying to identify connected subgraphs.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70794848/identifying-groups-networks-of-customers/70795252#70795252

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to calculate the connected subgraphs from the network that your connections build. See this previous question.  [Identifying groups/networks of customers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70794848/identifying-groups-networks-of-customers/70795252#70795252)

In your case the node ID variables are character instead of numeric.  The macro mentioned in that other question has been updated to handle character node ids https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/subnet.sas

It sounds like your connections are not one-way so disable the directed option.

```
filename src url 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sasutils/macros/master/subnet.sas';
%include src;
%subnet
(in=in01
,out=want
,from=primary_party_no 
,to=secondary_party_no 
,directed=0
);
proc print data=want;
run;
```

Results:

```
       primary_    secondary_
Obs    party_no     party_no     subnet

  1       A            B            1
  2       A            C            1
  3       B            A            1
  4       B            D            1
  5       C            A            1
  6       D            B            1
  7       W            Z            2
  8       X            Y            2
  9       Y            X            2
 10       Y            Z            2
 11       Z            W            2
 12       Z            Y            2
```

Comment: brilliant solution! works like a charm - i am still messing around with it a bit more in hopes of tweaking performance, as this runs rather long with my 600k records.

Comment: If you have SAS/OR licensed the use PROC OPTNET instead.

Comment: I ended up not having SAS/OR and fixed the performance problem by adding additional filter criteria, to keep the number of records that have to be looped to a minimum.