# SAS Studio: Finding Values of Column 2 in Column 1 Until Column 2 is Specific Value

Tags: sas

I have a simple question that I can't seem to answer. I HAVE a large data set where I am searching for values of column 2 that are found in column 1, until column 2 is a specific value. Sounds like a DO loop but I don't have much experience using them. Please see image as this likely will explain better.

Essentially, I have a "starting" point (with the first_match flag=1). Then, I want to grab the value of column 2 in this row (B in this example). Next, I want to search for this value (B) in column 1. Once I find that row (with column 1 = B & column 2 = C), I again grab the value in column 2 (C). Again, I find where in column 1 this new value occurs and obtain the corresponding value of column 2. I repeat this process until column 2 has a value of Z. That's my stopping point. The WANT table shows my desired output.

My apologies if the above is confusing, but it seems like a simple exercise that I can't seem to solve. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Glad to supply further clarification as well.

Have & Want

[image: 1]

I have tried PROC SQL to create flags and grab the appropriate rows, but the code is extremely bulky and doesn't seem efficient. Also, the example I laid out has a desired output table with 3 rows. This may not be the case as the desired output could contain between 1 and 10 rows.

Comment: You seem to have a directed graph.  The values in COL1 are directed to the value in COL2.  B->C->Z   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70794848/identifying-groups-networks-of-customers/70795252#70795252

Answer (score 3):

This question has been asked and answered previously.

Path traversal can be done using a DATA Step hash object.

Example:

```
data have;
length vertex1 vertex2 $8;
input vertex1 vertex2;
datalines;
A B
X B
D B
E B
B C
Q C
C Z
Z X
;

data want(keep=vertex1 vertex2 crumb);
  length vertex1 vertex2 $8 crumb $1;

  declare hash edges ();
  edges.defineKey('vertex1');
  edges.defineData('vertex2', 'crumb');
  edges.defineDone();

  crumb = ' ';
  do while (not last_edge);
    set have end=last_edge;
    edges.add();
  end;

  trailhead = 'A';

  vertex1 = trailhead;
  do while (0 = edges.find());
    if not missing(crumb) then leave;
    output;
    edges.replace(key:vertex1, data:vertex2, data:'*');
    vertex1 = vertex2;
  end;

  if not missing(crumb) then output;

  stop;
run;
```

All paths in the data can be discovered with an additional outer loop iterating (HITER) over a hash of the vertex1 values.

[image]