# Data grouping issue in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a data structure as follows, where the data store which customer is related to which customer.

```
data customer;
    input customer $ relate_cus $;
    datalines;
A B
A C
B A
B D
C A
C D
D C
D .
E F
E .
F E
F .
;
run;
```

I am trying to figure out a way to group all related customers, which I would like to group them up even if they are not directly related. For example in the above data, A, B, C, D should group into one group but E and F should be group into another group.

I have no idea where to start, would like to seek some insight here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This has been asked already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70794848/identifying-groups-networks-of-customers

Answer (score 0):

Hash tables to the rescue! Not thoroughly tested on all scenarios, expect you'll need to sort your data initially.

```
data customer;
    infile cards missover ;
    input customer $ relate_cus $;
    datalines;
A B
A C
B A
B D
C A
C D
D C
D .
E F
E .
F E
F .
;
run;
proc sort ; by customer relate_cus ; run ;
proc print ; run ;

data _null_ ;
  set customer end=eof ;
  
  length group groupno 8. customer relate_cus $1.;
  retain group . ;
  
  if _n_ = 1 then do ;
    declare hash cg() ;
    cg.definekey('customer');
    cg.definedata('customer','groupno') ;
    cg.definedone() ;
  end ;
  
  putlog customer= relate_cus= ;
  /* Does this customer exist in a group already? */
  rc = cg.find(key:customer) ;
  if rc > 0 then do ;
    putlog "Customer " customer " not found" ;
    /* not found - create a new group */
    group + 1 ;
    /* add the customer */
    putlog "1. Adding Customer " customer " to " group ;
    rc = cg.add(key:customer,data:customer,data:group) ;
    
    /* add the relate_cus */
    if not missing(relate_cus) then do ;
      putlog "2. Adding Related Customer " relate_cus " to " group ;
      rc = cg.add(key:relate_cus,data:relate_cus,data:group) ;
    end ;  
  end ;
  else 
  if not missing(relate_cus) then do ;   
    /* check relate_cus is assigned a group */
    rc = cg.find(key:relate_cus) ;
    if rc > 0 then do ;
      rc = cg.add(key:relate_cus,data:relate_cus,data:groupno) ;
      putlog "3. Adding Related Customer " relate_cus " to " groupno ;
    end ;
  end ;
  
  if eof then do ;
    /* output the hash table */
    rc = cg.output(dataset:'groups') ;
  end ; 
run ;
proc print data=groups noobs ;  run ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to your input, and after some more research on hash tables, I was able to get the result I wanted. Thanks again.

Comment: I've added a more robust hash answer to the question Tom mentioned (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70794848/identifying-groups-networks-of-customers).  The example data in that answer has groups that eventually bridge to other groups.