# SAS logic to populate 1 row based on another row

Tags: sas

I have a SAS dataset like this:

```
Name MgrName Dept.

A     B
B     C
C     D
X     Y
```

I need to fill in the Dept. using a recursive logic. I know D is the head of 'Payroll', so I fill in:

```
Name MgrName Dept.

A     B
B     C
C     D       Payroll
X     Y
```

But using some kind of recursion,everybody that is in D's reporting chain (A, B,C) also needs to be assigned 'Payroll'. How can I do that in SAS?

Comment: Can your data have more than one value with MgrName='D'?

Comment: Thank you. No, data is such that both 'Name' and 'MgrName' are unique.

Comment: Do names ever have more than one manager?  That should be rare but might happen in some organizations. Can managers have more than one  direct report?  That would be normal as otherwise you will have N-1 managers for N employees.

Comment: Note that your NAME->MGRNAME pairs basically are defining a graph.  Here is previous question about how to find the connected sub graphs.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525187/identifying-connected-graphs-given-edges

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hash based approach in the context of a `Proc DS2` program.

Each node (name) has only one parent (mgrname) so a hash can key with name and have mgrname as data.  A loop over find method will seek the ancestral parent for a node or not find one.

Example (name is `id` and namemgr is `pid`):

```
data have;
input id $ pid $;datalines;
A     B
B     C
C     D
F     D
G     F
H     F
P     H
Q     H
R     H
X     Y
run;

proc ds2;
  data want / overwrite=yes;
    declare package hash links();

    declare char _seek_pid;
    declare char _seek_id;
    declare char dept;

    keep id pid dept;

    * populate hash;
    method init();
      links.definekey('id');
      links.definedata('pid');
      links.dataset('{select pid, id from have {options locktable=share}}');
      links.multidata('yes');
      links.definedone();
    end;

    * seek ancestor from which value should be applied;
    method apply(char rootid, char value, char id);
      declare int limit;

      limit = 0;

      _seek_id = id;

      do while (
         links.find([_seek_id], [_seek_pid]) = 0 and 
         limit < 100 and 
         rootid ne _seek_pid
      );
        limit+1;
        _seek_id = _seek_pid;
      end;

      if rootid = _seek_pid then dept = value;
    end;

    * apply some values to some nodes and children thereof;    
    method run();
      set have (locktable=share);
      apply ('D','payroll', id);
      apply ('F','shadow$', id);
    end;
  enddata;
  run;
quit;

%let syslast = want;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a smarter way, but here is a hash object approach

```
data have;
input Name $ MgrName $;
datalines;
A B
B C
C D
X Y
;

data want(drop=rc);
   declare hash h1(dataset:'have');
   h1.definekey('MgrName');
   h1.definedata('Name');
   h1.definedone();
   declare hash h2();
   h2.definekey('Name');
   h2.definedone();

   length Name $ 100 MgrName $ 100;

   do rc=h1.find(key:'D') by 0 while (rc=0);
      h2.replace();
      rc=h1.find(key:Name);
   end;

   do until (lr);
      set have end=lr;
      Dept=ifc(h2.check()=0, 'Payroll', '');
      output;
   end;
run;
```