# Selecting one row per id for multiple accounts using SAS

Tags: sql, arrays, sas, left-join, proc

I have the following dataset where an id has multiple related id and sometimes a related id has one or more additional related ids. All that I need is to create dataset with one row per id with their related accounts information.

```
 Have:
      Id       Rel_ID
      1001      1001b
      2001      2001b
      2001b     2001c
      2001c     2001d
      2001d     2001e
      3001      3001b
 Want:
      Id       Rel_Id1     Rel_Id2    Rel_id3    Rel_Id4   Rel_Id5
      1001     1001b
      2001     2001b       2001c      2001d       2001e
      3001     3001b
```

I would be using most recent Rel_Id from this dataset for each id (e.g. for 2001 - 2001e)

I am creating SAS datasteps to do a left join and I will not know how many rel_ids an ids can  have

```
  proc sql;
   create table Relid1 as select 
   a.id,b.rel_id 
   from Have a
   left join Have b 
   on a.Rel_id=b.Id;
  quit;
```

I would be repeating the same using `Relid1` until I find zero matches. Is there an efficient way to get this done using arrays/macros.

Comment: Please read docs on `proc transpose` where you are reformatting data from long to wide format.

Comment: What is the logic that is going from ID values on the input that include letter suffixes to ID values on the output without any letter suffixes?  Are you trying to traverse a connected subgraph?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70794848/identifying-groups-networks-of-customers/70795252#70795252

Comment: This is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525187/identifying-connected-graphs-given-edges

Answer (score 4):

No need for SQL for something like that.  Just use PROC TRANSPOSE.

```
proc transpose data=have out=want(drop=_name_) prefix=Rel_Id ;
  by id;
  var rel_id;
run;
```

If your real question is how to form the related subgroups then look at this earlier question:  [Identifying groups/networks of customers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70794848/identifying-groups-networks-of-customers/70795252#70795252)

So let's make a dataset of your example input:

```
data have;
  input Id $ Rel_ID $;
cards;
1001      1001b
2001      2001b
2001b     2001c
2001c     2001d
2001d     2001e
3001      3001b
;
```

And get a copy of the %SUBNET macro so we can use it:

```
filename subnet url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sasutils/macros/master/subnet.sas";
%inc subnet;
```

Now we can calculate the subnets:

```
%subnet(in=have,out=subnet,from=id,to=rel_id,subnet=subnet,directed=1);
```

And use the first ID as the ID for all of the members of the subnet.

```
data subnet;
 set subnet;
 by subnet;
 if first.subnet then first_id=id;
 else id=first_id;
 retain first_id;
 drop first_id;
run;
```

Now we can transpose:

```
proc transpose data=subnet out=want(drop=_name_) prefix=Rel_Id;
  by id;
  var rel_id;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs     Id     Rel_Id1    Rel_Id2    Rel_Id3    Rel_Id4

 1     1001     1001b
 2     2001     2001b      2001c      2001d      2001e
 3     3001     3001b
```